# How to infer a type on only one deconstructed variable from an object

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I have a useForm hook that takes an object and returns several useful functions back, including that object as a state.
However, since useForm hook accepts dynamic objects, it cannot return the specific type from that initial object due to typescript limitations

```
export const useForm = (initialInputData: DynamicForm) => {
//...
return {inputFields, setInputFields, inputProps, resetFields, setInputField} as const;
}
```

So as you can see, useForm returns 5 variables. setInputFields, inputProps, resetFields, setInputField are returned with a proper type as they don't accept dynamic types

However, inputFields is dynamically generated and I need to infer a proper type on it in each functional component when I use the hook.

```
export const AddAdminDialog: FC<IProps> = (props) => {
//I only want to infer type on inputFields (inputFields gets the correct type, but typescript wants me to do that to other variables too), and not other fields as they are already properly typed.
  const {inputFields, setInputFields, inputProps} : {inputFields: typeof initialInputData} = useForm(initialInputData);
```

How can I only infer type on only one deconstructed variable without calling useForm twice and without inferring types for other variables that are already typed?

How does useQuery hook do it with useQuery() when it also returns a dynamic data back?

Please tell if there are any more ways to make this possible :)

Comment: What are you typing it as in the 1st place? Is it `any` before you type assert it as `typeof initialInputData` ? Why don't you create an extra variable, assign `inputFields` to it and assert its type?

Comment: It is typed as  a record of any strings and known properties. Since the hook can accept multiple different initialInputFields, I need to add correct type to it for that specific functional component after the hook returns that variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couldn't you use an extra variable?

```
export const AddAdminDialog: FC<IProps> = (props) => {
  const {inputFields, setInputFields, inputProps} = useForm(initialInputData);
  const aux = inputFields as XXX;  // CAN'T YOU DO THIS?
}
```

Comment: I actually didn't think about it. I was looking for one line solution but this works just fine! Thank you~